# Angular promise multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to replicate a couchDB like system.
My backend is Parse server and my frontend is Ionic (1)

What i'm trying to achieve is to fasten my application with localstorage.

Currently:
GetUserAds

-> Has localstorage?

--> Yes

---> Return localstorage

--> No

---> Get database call

----> Return and put local

But what i really would like is the local return to fetch the database in background and return that data as well if it's changed

This is because my application has many users and changes a lot.

Could i do something like this.

```
getUserAds(user).then(function(data) {
//Local data
}).then(function(dataDB) {
//Database updated data
})
```

Comment: You should enventualy take a look to the Observable of RxJS basicly it's promise that can be resolve multiple times which fits to you need. You can also use object, I did that in a project, I have an user object that gets filled by the localStorage then I make my API calls because it is an object the attributs changed by the API answer are change everywhere my object is used.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, looking into rxjs now, but all i find is ES6 or Angular2. Do you have more info on the Objects? not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: RxJS Observable has replaced promise in angular2 this is why you find a lot of ressources on it related to angular2. [here](https://youtu.be/KOOT7BArVHQ) is a youtube video of Ben Lesh that explain how it works. For the Object part I was thinking of a User Object `{name: 'fougere', ...}` which stores your user informations with a function getUserAds which simply get the data form the storage (cache/database/whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `notify` callback provided on angular promises:

```
function UserService($timeout, $q) {
    var users = ["user1", "user2"]; //localStorage.getItem('users');
    function get() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //call your backend here $http.get('....')
    $timeout(function() {
      //if(remoteUsers !== users) {
                deferred.resolve({local: false, users: users.concat('user3')});
      //}

    }, 3000);
    $timeout(function() {
    if(users) {
        deferred.notify({local: true, users: users});
    }

    }, 100)

    return deferred.promise;
  }

    return {
    get: get
  };
}
```

and in your controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $users) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.myUsers = [];

    $users.get()
        .then(setUsers, null, setUsers);

     function setUsers(users) {
        $scope.myUsers = users;
      }
}
```

Here you can see a little jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1596/

Comment: Spot on!

Just for my info, the notifiy is like a temporary resolve?

Comment: From the documentation: 
"Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected."
Essentially you can call whoever is waiting for your promise to be completed publishing the progress of your promise, as many times as you need, of course before resolving the promise.

Comment: Thanks really helpfull, this looks like the new observe pattern actually, but working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you use this service from the Angular API:
[Angular Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

This is how I would do it:

```
getUserAds(user).then(function(response) {
    // useMyData
});

function getUserAds {
    if( thereIsLocalData ) {
        return getLocalData(); // this returns a $q promise
    } else {
        return getDataDB() // Here I'm returning an $http Promise
    }
}

function getDataDB (params)  {
    return $http.get(host, params, {}); // I'm returning the $http Promise!
}

function getLocalData (params) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(myLocalData);
  }); // return the $q promise!
}
```

This way you are using local communications the same way as Online communications and you can simplify your logic.

Comment: This is actually how i'm using it right now, but this method can only return 1 time, which may cause the local data to be out of data..

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. Do you want your getLocalData to try a getDataDB too?

Comment: Yes correct, so get local first for speed, but also get db data and update once you get that.